# PHP date_sun_info() wrong start time

Tags: php

Im using the build-in PHP function date_sun_info(); which returns a array with times for the sunset/sunrise. My start time doesnt match the expecting value (06:22) but my end time does. My start time is 3 minutes behind the sunset time. Anyone knows why?

```
$today    = Carbon::now()->timestamp; //Timestamp of now
$sunTimes = date_sun_info( $today, 51.9229, 4.5866 );
$sunRise  = Carbon::createFromTimestamp( $sunTimes['sunrise'] )->format( 'H:i' );
$sunSet   = Carbon::createFromTimestamp( $sunTimes['sunset'] )->format( 'H:i' );

/**
 * Sunrise: 06:19
 * Sunset: 20:58
 * $today: 1461662744
 */
```

Comment: Are the `date.sunrise_zenith` and `date.sunset_zenith` values in your `php.ini` file set correctly? And see [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49448)

Comment: Thank you Mark, i didnt expected that. I changed my php.ini and still have no success with this issue.